# C++: How to convert 'const char*' to char

Tags: c++, string, char, constants

I know there are a lot of questions like this out there on StackOverflow, but I haven't been able to find any that help resolve my case. Whenever I try to do something like this:

```
// str = some string or char array

// some magic to get around fpermissive errors
stringstream convert;
convert << str;
// capture the stream's temporary string
const string store = convert.str();
// get a manageable array
const char* temp = store.c_str();
```

and then try to do something like `atoi(temp[0])`, I keep getting the classic conversion error that char couldn't be converted to const char. In the documentation for `atoi` and many other functions, const char is a required parameter. How can a char be sent in if there's only a const one? Does retrieving a char at a specific position auto-cast to char?

Comment: How about `atoi(temp)` instead of `atoi(temp[0])`?

Comment: `atoi(temp[0])` is incorrect because `atoi` expects a `char *` (a pointer to char), but `temp[0]` is just a single `char`.

Comment: "some magic to get around fpermissive errors"...those are almost certainly bugs. Fix them rather than attempting to work around them.

Comment: *"In the documentation for atoi and many other functions, `const char` is a required parameter."* Actually, it's `const char *`, and the `const` part is not a requirement. It's documentation that `atoi` promises not to change the input string.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: I have multiple "subscopes", so that's why I don't do that. On top of that, I just want one char at a specific position.

Comment: @T145: Then you don't want `atoi()`. To convert a single `char`, `temp[0] - '0'` will do it.

Comment: That'll just lead to a `invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’` error in the `atoi`. The reason why I want `atoi` is because the user is sending in a string, and I'm working from that.

Comment: @T145: Not unless you're doing something very strange. If you're calling `atoi()` then you want an `int` - there's no conversion from `int` to `const char *` if you do `int n = temp[0] - '0';`

Comment: OK, tell us exactly what you want your code to accomplish. Given a string `"12345"`, what do you want to get from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what is causing the error, but atoi takes as its parameter not a char, but the pointer to one. So instead of
    atoi(temp[0])

try this

```
atoi(&temp[0])
```

as that is a pointer.