# C convert const char * to char

Tags: c, char, switch-statement

I searched quite a while to find the answer, but I could only find a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290063/c-how-to-convert-const-char-to-char) for `C++` that didn't seem to work for `C`. I'm trying to convert argument of `const char *` to `char` to use in my `switch` statement. I tried various things like `strdup()`, but was unsuccessful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    char argOne = argv[1];
    char argTwo = argv[2];

    switch(argOne) {
        case '1234' :
            printf("1234!\n" );
            break;
        default :
        printf("Invalid\n" );
    }
}
```

While compilation:

> warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
>
> ```
> char argOne = argv[1];
>      ^        ~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> warning: overflow converting case value to switch condition type (825373492 to 52) [-Wswitch]
>
> ```
> case '1234' :
>      ^
> ```

Comment: You need to start with a basic C tutorial. There are numerous things wrong with your code.

Comment: which tutorial? i did studied this for hours, just need a hint.

Comment: One that takes you from pointers through chars and c-strings to switch/case statements.

Comment: okay, but then i spend hours looking for that through endless garbage. i'm not looking for recommendation, but rather name of tutorial you mention.

Comment: Nearly any tutorial. If doesn't have to cover anything complex.

Comment: okay thanks, but any tutorial might be the reason why i am here posting. i used earlier one that really didn't explain that i couldn't use a string in a switch statement, which is why i ended up posting this question.

Comment: +1 for compiling with warnings enabled and taking notice of these warnings - many noobs make the mistake of either not enabling warnings, or just ignoring warnings, and that can be fatal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code,

- Point 1:

  ```
   char argOne = argv[1];
  ```

  is very wrong. You cannot put a `const char *` (pointer) to a `char` variable.
- Point 2:

  ```
    case '1234'
  ```

  also wrong. Here, the `'1234'` **does not** denote a string. It is a multibyte charcater, which is most probably something you don't want. Again, even you change that to something like `"1234"`, still it would be *incorrect*, as it will not give you the *intended* value, and *strings* cannot be used for `case` statement *values*.

Solution:  Instead of using the `switch` case here,  you can try using [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to compare the incoming string and chose accordingly.

---

Note: The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: about your note, is there a reason for the recommended signature of `char *` instead of `const char *`? i was using `const char *` because it seemed easier to convert a `string` into it perhaps; maybe i'm mistakin.

Comment: @JackBauer Yes, because that signature in my NOTE is mentioned in the C standard. You can lookup `C11` doc, chapter 5.1.2.2.1 for more reference on the same. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You're getting mixed up between `char` (character) and `char *` (string). Also you can not use strings as switch/case labels. Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    const char *argOne = argv[1];
    const char *argTwo = argv[2];

    if (strcmp(argOne, "1234) == 0)
    {
        printf("1234!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid\n");
    }        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't realize strings could not be used in switch statements. i was following this tutorial earlier, but i noticed they only used a single char... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm

Comment: Yes, if you read that tutorial carefully you'll see that you can use individual `char`s in a switch statement, e.g. `'A'`, but not strings.

Comment: makes sense. one more question - if i had a `const char *a = "a";` could it still not be converted easily into `char`? i know probably a dumb question.

Comment: You can access the any individual character in a string using normal array indexing, so for your example you could say: `char b = a[0];` - this would set `b` to `'a'`.

Comment: thanks again - your answer really helped, i wish it were possible to mark more than one answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the standard declaration of main looks like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
                   ^^^^^^
```

That is the second parameter does not have qualifier `const`.

Secondly argv[1] has type `char *`. There is no any sense to compare it with a **character** literal similar to `'1234'`.  As for **string** literal `"1234"` when it may not be used in the case label.

What you want is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if ( argc > 2 )
    { 
        char *argOne = argv[1];
        char *argTwo = argv[2];

        if ( strcmp( argOne, "1234" ) == 0 )
        {
            puts( "1234!" );
        }
        else
        {
            puts( "Invalid" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this explanation, it really helps. i will study this carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (really) "convert" a pointer to `char` to a single `char`. You can however *extract* one single character from a string.

For example, to get the first character of the first argument to your program, you can do e.g.

```
char first_char_of_first_arg = 0;
if (argv > 1)
    first_char_of_first_arg = argv[1][0];
```

Comment: interesting,  i didn't realize switch statements could only use single `chars`., but makes sense now by what you mention. thanks

Answer (score 0):

the code contains several problems

compiling with all warnings enabled would allow the compiler to
display those problems.

for gcc, at a minimum, use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'

Note: warnings need to be fixed, as the compiler knows the C language better than you or I.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    //<< parameter argc not used
    //   and it should be used to assure that argv[1] and argv[2] actually exist

    char argOne = argv[1];
    //<< argv[1] is a pointer to a character string.
    //   argOne is a single char
    //   it should be: 'char argOne = argv[0][0];'

    char argTwo = argv[2];
    //<< argv[2] is a pointer to a character string.
    //   argTwo is a single character
    //   it should be: 'char argTwo = argv[1][0];'
    //<< argTwo is not used

    switch(argOne)
    //<< a character can be treated as an int, but due care needs to be exercised
    {
        case '1234' :
        //<< a case statement can only look at an 'int',
        //   not a pointer to a (in this case unterminated) string
        //   and argOne is a single char, not a pointer to a unterminated string
            printf("1234!\n" );
            break;
        default :
        printf("Invalid\n" );
        //<< for human readability, use consistent indentation
        //   and never use tabs for indenting
        //<< every case should be terminated with 'break;'
        //   unless the case is to fall through to the next case
        //   I.E. just because a syntax 'can' be used does not mean it 'should' be used
    }
}
```